# value appears when adding blank lines

Tags: awk

I have the following data file that contains blocks of columns. Between blocks I have blank lines like below:

```
1   11.298  0.000E+00  0.000E+00                                                                                    
1   11.308  0.000E+00  0.000E+00                                                                                    
1   11.318  0.000E+00  0.000E+00                                                                                    
1   11.328  0.000E+00  0.000E+00                                                                                    
1   11.338  0.000E+00  0.000E+00                                                                                    
                                                                                                                    
2  -54.322  0.582E-11  0.582E-11                                                                                    
2  -54.312  0.279E-09  0.279E-09                                                                                    
2  -54.302  0.454E-08  0.454E-08                                                                                    
2  -54.292  0.251E-07  0.251E-07                                                                                    
2  -54.282  0.470E-07  0.470E-07
```

So there are several such files and I am using the following awk action (? I don't know the proper term for this) to add column 3 from all files but preserver columns 1 and 2 and write the result in a new file.

```
awk '{a[FNR]=$1; b[FNR]=$2; s[FNR]+=$3} END{for (i=1; i<=FNR; i++) print a[i], "   ", "   ", b[i], "   ", s[i]}' file_1 file_2 > result.dat
```

The trouble is that in the result file I was expecting to see the blank line separating the blocks as above. Instead I get the following:

```
1         11.268     0                                                                                                    
1         11.278     0                                                                                                    
1         11.288     0                                                                                                    
1         11.298     0                                                                                                    
1         11.308     0                                                                                                    
1         11.318     0                                                                                                    
1         11.328     0                                                                                                    
1         11.338     0                                                                                                    
              0                                                                                                           
2         -54.322     4.26015e-05                                                                                         
2         -54.312     0.00204007                                                                                         
2         -54.302     0.0332012                                                                                          
2         -54.292     0.183007                                                                                           
2         -54.282     0.344012                                                                                           
2         -54.272     0.219008                                                                                           
2         -54.262     0.0472017
```

Note the `0` that appears on that blank line. Why does this happen and how can I prevent it from happening?

The expected output should look like below:

```
1         11.268     0                                                                                                    
1         11.278     0                                                                                                    
1         11.288     0                                                                                                    
1         11.298     0                                                                                                    
1         11.308     0                                                                                                    
1         11.318     0                                                                                                    
1         11.328     0                                                                                                    
1         11.338     0                                                                                                    

2         -54.322     4.26015e-05                                                                                         
2         -54.312     0.00204007                                                                                         
2         -54.302     0.0332012                                                                                          
2         -54.292     0.183007                                                                                           
2         -54.282     0.344012                                                                                           
2         -54.272     0.219008                                                                                           
2         -54.262     0.0472017
```

The third column of the output is the sum of the third columns from file1 file2 etc. Please note that file1 file2 etc have the same structure so as an example you can use the same input data from my example. My problem if with the 0 that appears on the blank line.

Comment: Don't use `FNR` as the index, unless you also save another array for `blanks[FNR]=NF` so you can capture which line(s) are blank. You can check `if (!blanks[i]) print""`

Comment: @Thor yes, the 3rd column in the output is the accumulated sum. Sorry I thought that was clear. I know it is not shown. The numerical values don't matter in this example, just that 0 that appears every time it encounters a blank like in file1 file2 etc

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I am sorry but I have no idea how to integrate your suggestion. I have cobbled together this command from many searches and I have been using it like this. For this data that I have with blank lines I get this problem.

Comment: No worries, @Daweo shows in his answer how to put the pieces together. Nice.

Comment: @Thor I am sorry it is unclear for you. Somehow it was clear from Daweo and I got a really good answer. Other than that blank line there is nothing of interest regarding the numerical values. anyway thank you for your input

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why does this happen

When GNU `AWK` was ordered to `{a[FNR]=$1; b[FNR]=$2; s[FNR]+=$3}` and it does encounter empty line this means referencing out of range fields. `$1`, `$2` and `$3` here are *unassigned* variables (see [Variable Typing in The GNU Awk User's Guide](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Variable-Typing.html)), they generally behave like empty string when you try to use them as string and like `0` when you try to use them as numeric, therefore `print`ing them is same as `print`ing empty strings and `s[FNR]+=$3` is same as `s[FNR]+=0`

> how can I prevent it from happening?

I would ameloriate your code following way

```
awk '{blank[FNR]=NF==0; a[FNR]=$1; b[FNR]=$2; s[FNR]+=$3} END{for (i=1; i<=FNR; i++){print blank[i]?"":(a[i]"         "b[i]"     "s[i])}}' file_1
```

then for file_1 content being

```
1   11.298  0.000E+00  0.000E+00                                                                                    
1   11.308  0.000E+00  0.000E+00                                                                                    
1   11.318  0.000E+00  0.000E+00                                                                                    
1   11.328  0.000E+00  0.000E+00                                                                                    
1   11.338  0.000E+00  0.000E+00                                                                                    
                                                                                                                    
2  -54.322  0.582E-11  0.582E-11                                                                                    
2  -54.312  0.279E-09  0.279E-09                                                                                    
2  -54.302  0.454E-08  0.454E-08                                                                                    
2  -54.292  0.251E-07  0.251E-07                                                                                    
2  -54.282  0.470E-07  0.470E-07
```

output is

```
1         11.298     0
1         11.308     0
1         11.318     0
1         11.328     0
1         11.338     0

2         -54.322     5.82e-12
2         -54.312     2.79e-10
2         -54.302     4.54e-09
2         -54.292     2.51e-08
2         -54.282     4.7e-08
```

Explanation: I use array named `blank` to store information if given line is blank (it is if number of fields that is `NF` is equal zero), then I `print` based on value of `blank` array for given line. If it is blank empty string otherwise concatenation of value from arrays `a`, `b`, `s` and spaces is used. I used so-called ternary operator that condition`?`valueiftrue`:`valueiffalse. Note that I also changed how string is built, as now it should be easier to adjust number of spaces between selected elements.

(tested in gawk 4.2.1)

Comment: thank you for this detailed explanation! This is very clear now and I should be able to update this when other peculiarities arise!

Answer (score 1):

You may use an `awk` solution like this:

```sh
cat fmt.awk

{
   a[FNR] = $1
   b[FNR] = $2
   s[FNR] += $3
}
ENDFILE {
   for (i=1; i<=FNR; i++)
      if (a[i] == "")
         print ""
      else
         print a[i], b[i], s[i]
   print ""
   delete a
   delete b
   delete s
}

awk -v OFS='\t' -f fmt.awk file1 file2

1   11.298  0
1   11.308  0
1   11.318  0
1   11.328  0
1   11.338  0

2   -54.322 5.82e-12
2   -54.312 2.79e-10
2   -54.302 4.54e-09
2   -54.292 2.51e-08
2   -54.282 4.7e-08

1   11.298  0
1   11.308  0
1   11.318  0
1   11.328  0
1   11.338  0

2   -54.322 5.82e-12
2   -54.312 2.79e-10
2   -54.302 4.54e-09
2   -54.292 2.51e-08
2   -54.282 4.7e-08
```

Comment: use it on the result file you mean?

Comment: file1 and file2 have the same data format in them so use the same for an example. also the result file is the one that is created by the command in my question from the combination between file1 and file2

Comment: i am sorry but I don't understand your answer. how do I run this?

Comment: Can you tell me which part is not clear and why are you not able to run? It is just a modification of your suggested `awk` command.

Comment: sorry I made it work. I was trying to run it on a single line. How can I put this in an awk file and run it like a script?

Comment: Sure, check my updated answer again

Comment: Did this work out now?